# The type arguments for method 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.VertexBuffer.SetData<T>(T[])' cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, xna

I've got:

```
    public List<VertexPositionColor> chunk_vertices;
    public List<int> chunk_indices;
```

Then

```
VertexBuffer vertex_buffer;
vertex_buffer = new VertexBuffer(device, VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration, test_chunk.chunk_vertices.Count, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);

vertex_buffer.SetData(test_chunk.chunk_vertices);
```

I've tried:

```
vertex_buffer.SetData<VertexPositionColor>(test_chunk.chunk_vertices);
```

and

```
vertex_buffer.SetData<List<VertexPositionColor>>(test_chunk.chunk_vertices);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`VertexBuffer.SetData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb198836) method expects an array, so change `chunk_vertices` to an array, or use the code below:

```
vertex_buffer.SetData(test_chunk.chunk_vertices.ToArray());
```